# Message for You:) #2

Tags: cipher, wordplay, visual, letters

I got a letter from someone today. There was no name or address of sender but only some scrambled letters:

[image]

Inside the letter the text was written:

**Message for You:)**

and below that was scratch-able area, after scratching that I got encrypted message:

> TLFNIUOHIGCZ

Can you help me find out what is the message and who sent it?

**HINT 1:**

Sorry guys was away for some time but I found something weird that could be of some use. I photocopied the letter and in the copy I can see some watermarks. As my machine was not working properly so can't find what's written exactly but some dots around some letters. May be you guys could find something from it so sharing a pic of copy.

> [image]

**Hint 1 EDIT:**

> the watermark is only around lower case letters

**HINT 2:**

The correct photocopy of cover of letter: I can clearly see numbers around some letters.

> [image]

**HINT 3:**

> **Take pairs** from what you see and you will find **from part** of letter(don't expect only name:)).

**HINT 4:**

> Now, as you already played with lowers, its time for another type (**capitals**):) (keep in mind **Take Pairs**) also don't get confused by words you can always play with **letters**:P

**HINT 5:**

> Combine hint 3 and 4.

**EDIT:**

The first part of puzzle has been solved by tyobrien, So I will appreciate if anyone wanna solve the second part i.e. decode the actual message(independent of first part).

Comment: I see BG in there :P

Comment: haha so you are the secret sender!

Comment: If so, that phrase is just the right length to read RICKANDMORTY

Comment: The postman must be a genius.

Comment: Is the top-left word/jebberish is supposed to look like that? Because I can't read it.

Comment: I think i should say the first part is not related to cipher. may be related to words or something no idea about tag but definitely very simple:P

Comment: The hint is harder than the puzzle itself.

Comment: Actually its not that hard as you guys thinking:) may be you are all experts in puzzles so think that way, you should think like a newbie to crack it. Now thats a big hint too;P don't go so deep

Comment: @preet can letters be rarranged

Comment: yes, that's what they mean to. If you know appropriate tag for it feel free to edit

Comment: Take them as letters don't consider words these are only for distraction. Also both parts are independent you can try decrypting the message part first as well

Comment: Are the letters the watermarks are near supposed to be cursive script?

Comment: Another hint will be appreciated...

Comment: No @Barker it doesnt mean anything just missed print of something written. Sorry guys dont have access to pc till monday. Will update on monday. Till then i can say just pick lower letters first and think if you can make any words. Possibly 2.

Comment: The hint decodes to "take pairs". No idea where to go from there, though...

Comment: Are we expecting more hints?

Comment: ibrahimmahrir, i think no for first part now or it will be like telling about sender:P What can i say is @Lolgast got the idea to find text of the cover(another Hint).

Comment: Is it JV or JU on top-left corner?

Comment: @Kamome, its JV

Comment: I just have to say... this is the Freehand Red Circles version of a puzzle!

Comment: This is still unsolved! Oh my! I hope it won't stay like this untill 2019.

Comment: It's been about month when I saw this puzzle first time, and I'm still PUZZLING (ha.....). Preet said "try newbie's approach", but I'm still quite can't get it. :(
ps. By the way, because of this one, my working time became not as boring as before :)

Comment: If we take each lower case letter that has a pair we get “a” and each upper case letter that has a pair we get “JORETEM”.  Putting these together we have an anagram for “from Jeeta”...  just messing around.

Comment: @tyobrien you got it!! just you don't need that 'a'; you can post it as a answer if like..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the instructions to "take pairs"...

> we can take all the capital letters that have another capital letter.  This listing gives the letters **J, F, O, R, E, T, E, M**.  This is an anagram for "From Jeet".

Comment: Well done!! you solved the first part of puzzle.. Try solving the second part. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is my second try i think answer can be

> MESSAGE FROM @PREET

```
ULFNIUOHIGCZ
```

> HAPPYNEWYEAR = HAPPY NEW YEAR

Ignore me if this is not the answer
Sorry , there will be a delay in explanation of my answer exams are going on.

Comment: How’d you get Rick and Morty

Comment: @NapoleonofPuzzling With a brute force attack you get will get name for first four letters

Comment: I meant the ‘ AND MORTY ‘ part. Sorry, I should have been more specific.

Comment: @rudra thats not correct answers but i think i should clear onething dont know if you misunderstood it. The image part is for name of sender and encrypted message is the actual message written inside letter. Image is of the outside of letter.

Comment: @Preet i will try again

Comment: I think you should explain how you _got_ the answer rather than just what the answer is. Even if it's something as simple as "i just guessed based on the length of the code", it's still better than having the answer pop out of nowhere imo.

Comment: @rudra no idea how you got it but sorry to say you are not on right track but really wanna know how you get it

Answer (score 2):

Well If you take the hint from Hint 2 quite literally you get

> 1= t, 2=a, 3=k, 4=e, 5=p, 6=a, 7=i, 8=r, 9=s takepairs

I don't know how to apply that to the larger solution though
Should be a lead to figure out the name of the sender...maybe to the message as well

Comment: now you have hint, no need to decrypt it its there to guide you for next step, so move on

Answer (score 2):

Some hint that I am getting, which may probably be wrong, is that, we can caesar shift some of the capital letter words. So,

> JV->AM  FOR-> GPS  BG->IN  ME->AS

Although I can't do it for all the words.
Also, we can take pairs of alphabets, or
take pairs of words and jumble them, but I am not being able to reach close to any solution. I get it's a name, but decoding names can be quite hard.

Comment: I must say your second approach will be good and you will get from part of letter so don't expect only name. Try!

Answer (score 2):

I think the sender's name is Sofia.

> **BG** -> Bulgaria(Two letter country code) and the **capital** of Bulgaria is Sofia. :D

You said to look into to **Capitals** :P

Comment: I appreciate your thinking but sorry not correct, for me capital is what we say opposite of lower letters i.e. upper case letters:P